# Copy files from remote to local

Tags: scp

I tried to copy the file from remote to my local directory but I am getting an error No such file or directory.

Below is the command I used to copy

scp username@remoteserver.xxx:/path to the file/filename /path to the local directory/

All the paths I copied using pwd.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get "No such file or directory" for the

```
/path to the file/filename
```

or the

```
/path to the local directory/
```

part? If it's the first, then you might have an issue with the path itself. If it's for the second then specifying `localuser@localmachine:/path to the local directory/` might fix it. If you're on the same LAN, you could also try `localuser@localmachineip:/path to the local directory/`